# NHibernate auditing with Event listeners - how to create history object in IPreUpdateEventListener.OnPreUpdate

Tags: nhibernate

I'm taking advantage of great article:

http://ayende.com/blog/3987/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-ipreinserteventlistener

and have implemented **OnPreInsert** exactly like in the example. However, my auditing requirement when updating the entity, is to create a "history" entry in database. Let's say:

- I fetch Person object
- I modify

  personObj.FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
- then I save the entity. Now, in **IPreUpdateEventListener.OnPreUpdate** I want to change **UpdatedAt** & **UpdatedBy** properties of Entity & State (just like in the article), and **also I need** to add a new record to database that contains old values (**FirstName** before change).

I saw that **PreUpdateEvent** contains **OldState** array, however I have no idea how to create a **Person** object fron **OldState** array and save it.

How can I achieve what I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> however I have no idea how to create a Person object fron OldState array and save it.

Have you had a look at [NHibernate Envers](https://bitbucket.org/RogerKratz/nhibernate.envers)? It does just that.

If you don't want to use this framework for some reason, take a look at its source code.

Comment: I would like to use it, but I can't... Thanks